# Codable Firebase с ссылками

Tags: ios, swift, кодировка, decode

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно разобрать структуру полученную с Firebase если есть параметры которые используют ссылку:

Для примера:

```
“SETTINGS_SETS” : {
    “-L0zrlGjhWpCZQHSW61_” : [ {
      “PARAMETERS” : [ {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGjhWpCZQHSW61Z”
      }, {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGjhWpCZQHSW61Z”
      }, {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGo6tXoTUsVaoVO”
      } ]
    }, {
      “PARAMETERS” : [ {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGo6tXoTUsVaoVO”
      } ]
    } ],
    “-L0zrlGku5bO9BBDR2cM” : [ {
      “PARAMETERS” : [ {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGjhWpCZQHSW61W”
      }, {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGjhWpCZQHSW61Y”
      }, {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zr7lNbBusPwSG2mMc”
      }, {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGhVDjQ5nkq01Ll”
      } ]
    }, {
      “PARAMETERS” : [ {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGhVDjQ5nkq01Lk”
      } ]
    }, {
      “PARAMETERS” : [ {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGirpuKDjNEZ6T0"
      } ]
    }, {
      “PARAMETERS” : [ {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGirpuKDjNEZ6Sy”
      }, {
        “uid” : “PARAMETERS/-L0zrlGirpuKDjNEZ6Sx”
      } ]
    } ]
}
```

Я создал структуру:

```
struct Section: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let parameters: [String]?

    enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case parameters
    }

}
```

и Структуру параметра:

```
struct Parameter: Codable {
    let name: String?
}
```

По идее правильно должно быть указанно в структуре Секции массив параметров:

```
struct Section: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let parameters: [Parameter]?

    enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case parameters
    }

}
```

Но из за того что там указана ссылка не работает наполнение.

Подскажите пожалуйста как поступать в данных ситуациях???

Comment: Покажите часть оригинального JSON, то что вы привели как пример не понятно что из себя представляет.

Comment: Изменил в описании